# Intellij cannot select rendering target

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have been using Android Studio, that worked like a charm. Then I reinstalled my computer and switched to IntelliJ, but I kept the SDK on SD card so I don't have to re/downloading it.
It works, I can build an app, but layout editor is not working. I cant select rendering target.

Here is what I see.
[image: Here is what I see.]

When I open the dropdown menu to select rendering target it says just: `<null>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: @General_Twyckenham Why not? We have over 15500 inteliij-idea tagged questions and Rendering Android Layouts is a useful tool for programming. Plus if you look [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology), there is no StackExchange site for IDE issues.

Comment: @Harmelodic Fair point. I retract my issue

Comment: @user3706021 Have you properly configured the IntelliJ project with the Android SDK? I just started a new Android project and defined my Android SDK location for the project, however IntelliJ didn't select a particular SDK version to use. Check your Project Settings at `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S`.
Also check your Gradle settings to see if your SDK version has been defined there.

Comment: @Harmelodic thanks that worked. I had to make new project SDK different then the Java one and asign it to that project

Comment: Excellent, I'll add this as an answer, if you could accept so users in the future can find a solution that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

First download proper SDKs in the SDK manager, and then you need to select the device on which you want to preview. To do so, click on the icon of the two little phones left of the **AppTheme** above the editor.

Comment: This answer is void as the user has already pointed out when he tries to select the rendering Android version the dropdown menu shows `<null>`. Without a Android Version, the user cannot choose a device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have properly configured the IntelliJ project with the Android SDK.

Check your Project Settings at <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Also check your Gradle settings to see if your SDK version has been defined there.